# If possible, How to upgrade to Ubuntu 13.10 while keeping kernel 3.2 from 12.04?

Tags: upgrade, kernel

To expand my question, I would like to know how to upgrade Ubuntu 12. 04. 0 (kernel version 3. 2, compatible with the Intel GMA3600 driver provided with the package cedarview-drm) to Ubuntu 13. 10, keeping the 3. 2 kernel version for 2D acceleration purposes, and having the latest stable kernel alongside.

Of course, all this if it is possible.

Hardware here is Acer Aspire One D270, Intel Atom Processor with Intel GMA3600 (as mentioned, best driver option for this one is cedarview-drm, although gma500_gfx does give basic functions).

Comment: But isn't `cedarview-drm` only available for `12.04`...?

Comment: Yes, and now that I think about it Xorg would be a problem too, since versions 1.9 and 1.11 are the only compatible with this cedarview drivers.
So, this was a dumb question after all, guess will have to find a better way to deal with this. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

The cedarview package is only available for installation in Precise (12.04) as can be seen in the [package page](http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/precise-updates/cedarview-drm-drivers). I haven't seen reasons why if you don't compile the package it shouldn't work in newer kernels (since you can install newer kernels in precise) so that's an option if you feel like compiling from sources.

The package uses DKMS so unless you find a nasty bug, it should work.